# Why is my Jest spy of a module's function used in another module, not getting called when testing the latter module's function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a logging module set up like this:

`utils/debugLogger.js`

```
/** Logging to stderr/stdout etc using debug package */

const debug = require('debug');

// this will make sure all logging goes to console.info
// debug.log = console.info.bind(console);

const getLogger = (namespace) => {
  const logger = {
    log: debug(`${namespace}:log`),
    debug: debug(`${namespace}:debug`),
    warn: debug(`${namespace}:warning`),
    info: debug(`${namespace}:info`),
    error: debug(`${namespace}:error`)
  }
  logger.log.log = console.log.bind(console);
  logger.debug.log = console.debug.bind(console);
  logger.info.log = console.info.bind(console);
  logger.warn.log = console.warn.bind(console);
  logger.error.log = console.error.bind(console);
  return logger;
}

module.exports = getLogger;
```

And its mock implementation:

`utils/__mocks__/debugLogger.js`

```
const getLogger = () => {
  return {
    error: () => {},
    debug  : () => {},
    info  : () => {},
    warn: jest.fn().mockName('logger.warn-mock'),
    log: () => {},
  }
}

module.exports = getLogger;
```

And my module whose functions I want to test:

`helpers/myModule.js`

```
const logger = require('../utils/debugLogger')('helpers');

const helpers = {
  getCleanTimestamp: function() {
    // do something
    logger.warn("something was done")
    return;
  },
}

module.exports = helpers;
```

And the test to check if the logger.info was called with "something as done":

`__tests__/helpers.test.js`

```
jest.mock(__base + 'utils/debugLogger');
const helpers = require(__base + "helpers/helpers");
const logger = require('../../utils/debugLogger')('helpers');

describe('getCleanTimestamp', () => {
  it.only('should set off warnings for invalid timestamp', () => {
    const logwarnSpy = jest.spyOn(logger, 'warn');
    const now = helpers.getCleanTimestamp();
    expect(logwarnSpy).toBeCalledWith("something was done");
  });
});
```

I've done the following things correctly:

- I've mocked the debugLogger module
- did the import of debugLogger module after mocking it

But still I get this error:

```
 FAIL  server/__tests__/helpers.test.js
  getCleanTimestamp
    ✕ should set off warnings for invalid timestamp (5 ms)

  ● getCleanTimestamp › should set off warnings for invalid timestamp

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "something was done"

    Number of calls: 0

      37 |     jest.spyOn(logger, 'warn');
      38 |     // const logwarnSpy = jest.spyOn(logger, 'warn');
    > 39 |     expect(logger.warn).toBeCalledWith("something was done");
         |                         ^
      40 |   });
      41 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (server/__tests__/helpers.test.js:39:25)
```

Edit: Put in the edits as prescribed in first answer. Still not working though. Getting:

```
  ● getCleanTimestamp › should set off warnings for invalid timestamp

    expect(logger.warn-mock).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "something was done"

    Number of calls: 0

      52 |     const logInfoSpy = jest.spyOn(logger, 'warn');
      53 |     const now = helpers.getCleanTimestamp();
    > 54 |     expect(logInfoSpy).toBeCalledWith("something was done");
         |                        ^
      55 |   });
      56 | });
```

Comment: You spy on warn but the system under test calls info.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for pointing that out, I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The `jest.spyOn` statement should happen before the action you're testing. In addition, as @jonrsharpe mentioned, the spy should be set on the `info` method rather than `warn`.

```
it('should set off warnings for invalid timestamp', () => {
    const logInfoSpy = jest.spyOn(logger, 'info');
    const now = helpers.getCleanTimestamp();
    expect(logInfoSpy).toBeCalledWith("something was done");
});
```

Comment: I made this change. Still getting the error - I've appended that in the question.